# ef 7 - HttpGet return blank page when adding a .Include

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-web-api, navigation-properties

I'm trying to build a Web API that returns a list of posts and for each post its author. I'm working with EF7 beta7 MVC 5, all other stuff in beta7 and i'm using Visual Studio 2015. 
This is the code for my two entities:

```
public class User 
{
    // Primary key
    public int Id {get;set;}
    // Some attributes
    public string FirstName {get; set;} 
    public string LastName {get; set;}
    // Navigation methods
    [InverseProperty("Author")]
    public virtual ICollection<Post> PostsCreaded {get;set;}
    ... other stuff ...
}
public class Post 
{
    // Primary key
    public int Id {get;set;}
    // Attributes
    public string Text {get;set;}
    //Foreign Keys
    public int AuthorId {get;set;}
    ... other keys
    // Navigation methods
    [ForeignKey("AuthorId")]
    public virtual User Author{get;set;}
    ... other navigations
}
```

My DbContext:

```
public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
{
    public DbSet<User> MyUsers {get;set;}
    public DbSet<Post> Posts {get;set;}
    ...
}
```

This is my WEB API

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
public class PostController : Controller
{
    private ApplicationDbContext _db;

    public PostController(ApplicationDbContext db)
    {
        _db = db;
    }

    [HttpGet]
    public IEnumerable<Post> Get()
    {
        var t = _db.Post;
        return t.AsEnumerable();
    }
}
```

When i run the project and type http://localhost:3927/api/post i get the list of post as expected, BUT when i use .Include(x=>x.Author) i get a blank page with no error. I tryed the step by step debug, but the return value of the method is correct and contains the list of posts with the navigation property initialized. This is the version with Include

```
[HttpGet]
public IEnumerable<Post> Get()
{
    var t = _db.Post.Include(x => x.Author);
    return t.AsEnumerable();
}
```

I also tryed to add this code in the OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder) in my ApplicationDbContext but it didn't fix the problem.

```
builder.Entity<User>()
    .Collection(x => x.PostsCreaded )
    .InverseReference(y => y.Author)
    .ForeignKey(z => z.AuthorId);
builder.Entity<Post>()
    .Reference(x => x.Author)
    .InverseCollection(y => y.PostsCreaded)
    .ForeignKey(z => z.AuthorId);
```